# sql string escaping question

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to insert the same value more than once into an escaped string? ie

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 = %s || column2 = %s || column3 = %s) AND this = $s", $search_terms,$that");
```

If not, does anyone have a good alternative for a condition builder. The SQL is run more than once, on a selection of tables. Some tables have more columns to be searched than others, so I created a condition builder. But now I'm trying to escape the values to prevent SQL injects.

```
$conditions = "";
                $query_seperator = " || ";
                $i = 0;
                foreach($table['fields'] as $field){

                    if ($i < ($field_count-1)){
                        $conditions = $conditions . $field . " LIKE %s" . $query_seperator;
                    } else {
                        $conditions = $conditions . $field . " LIKE %s";
                    }

                    $i++;
                }

$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ($conditions) AND this = $s", $search_terms,$that");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be equivalent to

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE %s IN (column1,column2,column3) AND this = $s", $search_terms,$that");
```

Comment: You cant do that. WHERE IN only search strings. It wont search columns. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Did you try? Because it works perfectly well on my server. `IN ()` is just a shortcut for multiple `OR` statements and MySQL rewrites it to this form, before compiling the query.

Comment: i did try. I will try again just to be sure.